# Round number up in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following number

```
0.135
```

I'd like to round it to 2 decimal places, I'm using...

```
(newCostDiff/2).toFixed(2)
```

only this returns

```
0.13
```

Can anyvody advise me on how to do this?

Comment: try `Math.round(newCostDiff * 100)/100`

Comment: You can not do this with jQuery. Only with JavaScript.

Comment: @Lix [But... but... jQuery!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: I thought jQuery was javascript

Comment: The round answers given below are simply aliases of your toFixed() method... Although, with your example toFixed returns 0.14 on Chrome.

Comment: @Dale - jQuery is a JS library. JS is the actual language.

Comment: @Dale jQuery is library of useful JavaScript functions, methods, wrappers etc. For the basic stuff one should still use plain JavaScript. No point wrapping one-liner in other one-liner.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what jQuery is, sarcasm was lost :)

Answer (score 0):

What's need of jquery

```
var newCostDiff = 0.135;
Math.round(newCostDiff *100)/100; //returns 0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first multiply the result by 10^(number of decimals), then round the number, than divide this number by 10^(number of decimals).

In this case:

```
Math.round((newCostDiff/2)*100) / 100;
```